# Is it possible to give priority to browsers on a router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

i have a TPlink WR940N router and i want to give bandwidth priority to browsers. since some users download large files using download managers, i don't want other users who just browse the web to be affected. is this possible?

Comment: Most of the downloads are usually through HTTP GET method so it's not so possible to distinguish download data from the browsing data using network port, which is normally used for such bandwidth allocation. A solution can be limiting the bandwidth for each user, so everyone will have same bandwidth no matter if they download or browse. I don't know about this specific router but most of them do have such option.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that router does have some Quality of Service settings (QoS) which might enable you to downgrade some traffic types. However, QoS is notoriously difficult to get right on enterprise grade routers let alone consumer grade ones.

Simply put, if you don't have enough bandwidth, there isn't that much you can do other than increasing it.

A better answer might be to (if you can on that router) add a firewall or other rule limiting downloads.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "download managers" do you mean programs like BitTorrent or other peer-to-peer file sharing?  Because if that is the case, there is a very high likelyhood that you can set the QoS setting on the router to get your desired outcome.

Here is a link to a guide on logging into your router, based in the model # you provided.

[router login guide](http://m.setuprouter.com/router/tp-link/tl-wr940n/login.htm)

After you log in it should be easy to find the QoS settings, I haven't used your particular router before, but QoS is a pretty standard feature of SOHO routers like yours.  Contrary to what has been said here by others, I've found QoS pretty simple and reliable for small networks using only one access point, which seems to be your situation.

Once you're in, you might try raising the priority for web browsing or media streaming, as well as lowering priority for services you are trying to limit or discourage.

Good luck!

Comment: I have tried the Qos, but there are a lot of user that connect on the wifi and it's hard to manage all. and i mean download manager like "internet download manager" (idm).